# How do we solve for the $n\times n$ variance - covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, variance, covariance

Suppose that $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ follow a $n-$ dimensional multivariate normal with mean and variance - covariance matrix as below

$$(\mu_n, \Sigma_n) =\begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\ \mu_2 \\ \vdots\\ \mu_n\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{1,2} & \sigma_{1,3} & \cdots &  \sigma_{1,n} \\ \sigma_{2,1} & \sigma_2^2 & \sigma_{2,3} & \cdots & \sigma_{2,n} \\ \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\ \sigma_{n,1} & \sigma_{n,2} & \sigma_{n,3} & \cdots &  \sigma_n^2\end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}$$

In case where $n=2$ in order to calculate the dererminant of $\Sigma$ and find the inverse variance - covariance matrix we have the following formulas

$$|\Sigma_2| = \sigma_1^1\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2)$$

and hence

$$\Sigma_2^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma_1^1\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2)}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & -\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ -\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Assuming that the $n\times n$ variance co-variance matrix is positive semi-definite and the inverse matrix exists how do we solve for the determinant of $\Sigma_n$ and the inverse $n\times n$ variance - covariance matrix $\Sigma_n^{-1}$?

Let me make a try. Assuming that the inverse of the covariance matrix exists, then

$$|\Sigma| = \begin{vmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & \rho_{1,2}\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \rho_{1,3}\sigma_1\sigma_3 & \cdots & \rho_{1,n}\sigma_1\sigma_n \\
\rho_{2,1}\sigma_2\sigma_1 & \sigma_2^2 & \rho_{2,3}\sigma_2\sigma_3 & \cdots & \rho_{2,n}\sigma_2\sigma_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\rho_{n,1}\sigma_n \sigma_1 & \rho_{n,2}\sigma_n\sigma_2 & \rho_{n,3}\sigma_n\sigma_3 & \cdots & \sigma_n^2
\end{vmatrix} = Diag(\Sigma)^{-1/2} A Diag(\Sigma)^{-1/2}=\\=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\cdots\sigma_n^2|A|$$

where

$$Diag(\Sigma)^{-1/2} = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
0 & \sigma_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0& 0 & \cdots & \sigma_n \end{bmatrix}$$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho_{1,2} & \rho_{1,3}& \cdots & \rho_{1,n} \\
\rho_{2,1} & 1 & \rho_{2,3} & \cdots & \rho_{2,n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\rho_{n,1} & \rho_{n,2} & \rho_{n,3} & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Could anyone help from this step and beyond to find the co-factor matrix? All I need is a recursive formula

Comment: What do you mean "solve for" in this context? The formulas for the determinant of a matrix and the procedure to compute the inverse of a matrix are basic.

Comment: My question is simple! What are the steps for the calculations of the inverse $n\times n$ variance - covariance matrix. In the case where $n=2$ or $n=3$ it seems easy, but what is the general fomula? You need to do some calculations? use some properties from the symmetrix matrices or some kind of decomposition? This is what I am trying to figure out in order to do the calculations and find the inverse $n\times n$ variance - covariance matrix as in the case where $n=2$....

Comment: There are formulae for the inverse and determinant of matrices but they get very unwieldy and impractical for high $n$. The matrix being symmetric doesn't help much.

Comment: what is $\rho_{i,j}$ here? is it the partial correlation between two variables with respect to the others?

Comment: @RobertMurray exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Foreward: I say covariance matrix because its shorter and is synonymous to covariance-variance to the best of my knowledge.

The inverse of a covariance matrix (if it exists) is called a precision matrix. For a univariate distribution our explicit definition is:
$$p = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$
However, this does not translate to multivariate distributions. Let $\Sigma$ denote our covariance matrix for $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, and $P$ denote our precision matrix. We know that $P = \Sigma^{-1}$, so we can roughly define:

$$P = \frac{1}{\det(\Sigma)} \text{Adj}(\Sigma)$$
Where $\text{Adj}(\Sigma)$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix of $\Sigma$. Also, the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is defined as:

$$\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix} \text{Cov}(x_1, x_1) & \text{Cov}(x_1, x_2) & \ldots & \text{Cov}(x_1,x_n) \\ \text{Cov}(x_2,x_1) & \text{Cov}(x_2,x_2) & \ldots &\text{Cov}(x_2,x_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\text{Cov}(x_n,x_1) & \text{Cov}(x_n, x_2)& \ldots & \text{Cov}(x_n, x_n) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Not what you have written down. They are very, very different, so maybe you mean something else but you should change this word.

Outside of this, there are not many things that we can say about it without much more complex calculations, since each element of a precision matrix is not particularly saying anything. Wikipedia has a page on partial correlations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_matrix_inversion), which mention precision matrices and the properties of the elements but it won't do you much good. The only other formula I could find is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10795/how-to-interpret-an-inverse-covariance-or-precision-matrix), with the density of a normal distribution. Generally, the explicit formula for an inverse is the easiest to calculate, and we can do it in time complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ for a $n$ by $n$ matrix (I believe).

In sum, there is no known formula for the inverse of a covariance matrix, and I don't believe it's an open problem, which implies someone has proven it to be impossible to find.